# Get route path name inside Nuxt Config file

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, sitemap

I have app and I am playing around with sitemap generation.
For sitemap I am using @nuxtjs/sitemap - 2.4.0, and my idea is to run some functions for generating sitemaps dynamically only when user opens site map URL and not on every startup of server.

I am using nuxt/vue-app 2.15.8 and I was wondering what is the correct way to access current opened page/path inside Nuxt config file ?

This is config for sitemap itself:

```
{
    path: '/sitemaps/store-locations.xml',
    exclude: ['!**', '/'], // Skip all automatically generated routes
    i18n: true,
    xmlNs:
      'xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"',
    routes: async function () {
      //$route gets undefined
      if (this.$route.path.split('/').pop() !== 'store-locations.xml') return
      
      //heavy functions which makes a lot of calls to DB
      const { getStores } = require('../../helpers/sitemap/storeLocatorRoutes');

      return getStores();
    },
```

Comment: So, generating the sitemap on the fly? Like if the user goes to `/about`, run the sitemap just for this part?

Comment: Yes, exactly @kissu . Or sitemap file itself can be generated, but empty until accessed.

Comment: What's the point of such thing? The principle of a sitemap is to map your website with pure links only, no JS. I don't see why you would want to generate that on runtime. Also, you're using SSR or SSG?

Comment: I am using SSR. The point is that I want to reduce load to service which is called when generating sitemap for dynamic links.

Comment: Then, you could probably build that one (SSG-like) and use it statically alongside your SSR app when you deploy your app. `sitemap.xml` is available at root anyway no?

Comment: Can you give me a bit details or example how I can do that? Sitemap is inside root/sitemap/store-locations.xml.